# Local script output is saved on remote server if using invoke-command

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

Hello everyone and thank you for the help you are providing here,

I have the script bellow who is checking the list of process and memory then create a nice HTML file as a report, this script was working fine in my local  machine, once i added a loop + Invoke-Command and a list_server.txt to get process info for each server in list, I found out that the html file is saved  in C:/$server?documents for each server from the list. I want to save the HTML results in the local machine from which I run the script.

This is my script :

```
$serversname = Get-Content -Path Server_list.text

Foreach ($servername in $serversname)

{
    invoke-command -scriptblock {

$Header = @"

<style>
h1 {

        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #e68a00;
        font-size: 28px;
        text-align:center;
        margin: 0 auto;

    }

    
    h2 {

        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #000099;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-align:center;
        margin: 100 auto;

    }
table {
        width:50%;
        margin-left:auto; 
        margin-right:auto;
}

table {
        font-size: 12px;
        border: 0px; 
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    } 
    
    td {
        padding: 4px;
        margin: 0px;
        border: 0;
    }
    
    th {
        background: #395870;
        background: linear-gradient(#49708f, #293f50);
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 11px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
        background: #f0f0f2;
    }
    p {

        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #ff3300;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-align:center;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
"@

$properties=@(
    @{Name="Process Name"; Expression = {$_.name}}, 
    @{Name="Memory (MB)"; Expression = {[Math]::Round(($_.WorkingSet / 1mb ),2)}}
)  

#Getting all process

$ComputerName = "<h1>Nom du serveur : $env:computername</h1>"
$ProcessInfo = Get-process  | Select-Object $properties | Sort-Object  -Property "Memory (MB)" -Descending |  ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header  -PreContent "<h2>Informations sur les processus</h2>"
$Report = ConvertTo-HTML -Body " $ComputerName $ProcessInfo" -Title "Informations sur les processus Genetec" -PostContent "<p>Date de creation : $(Get-Date)<p>"
$Report | Out-File .\log.html

#Getting only Firefox process

$ProcessInfo_firefox = Get-process firefox | Select-Object $properties | Sort-Object  -Property "Memory (MB)" -Descending |  ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header  -PreContent "<h2>Informations sur les processus Firefox</h2>"
$Report = ConvertTo-HTML -Body " $ComputerName $ProcessInfo_firefox" -Title "Informations sur les processus Firefox" -PostContent "<p>Date de creation : $(Get-Date)<p>"
$Report | Out-File .\log_firefox.html

#Getting only Firefox process with more than 200Mb memory 

$ProcessInfo_firefox_plus200 =  Get-Process firefox   | Select-Object @{Name="Process Name"; Expression = {$_.name}},@{Name="Memory (MB)"; Expression = {[Math]::Round(($_.WorkingSet / 1mb ),2)}} | where {$_.'Memory (MB)' -gt 300} | ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header  -PreContent "<h2>Informations sur les processus Firefox qui utilise plus que 200mb de RAM</h2>"
$Report = ConvertTo-HTML -Body " $ComputerName $ProcessInfo_firefox_plus200" -Title "Informations sur les processus Firefox qui utilise plus que 200mb de RAM" -PostContent "<p>Date de creation : $(Get-Date)<p>"
$Report | Out-File .\log_firefox_plus200.html


} -computername $servername

}
```

Also please I have a second question, As you can see my script is generating an HTML file for each server, Can I somehow put all process tables in one HTML file not separately, Thank you so much.

Comment: [1] your loop is is dangerously named. this >>> Foreach ($servername in $serversname) <<< really otta be named something VIVIDLY different for the current item. having the only difference as a single letter buried in the middle of the word is ... poorly done. ///// [2] gather your data in the `I-C` call, send it back to the calling system ... and then build the report locally on the calling system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, I would never build the HTML report on the remote servers. But following your example code and given your "question" (I want to save the HTML results in the local machine from which I run the script.). This is what I would do, I have also enhanced your code a bit.

There is also no need to use `foreach` loops when invoking commands on remote servers unless there is a specific need for this. In your example, I don't see any particular or specific need to do each server at a time. Powershell allows you to invoke the same command on an array of servers, pretty similar as what it would do if all invocations would have been done using the `-AsJob` switch followed by a `Wait-Job`.

```
$style = @"
<style>
h1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #e68a00;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h2 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000099;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 100 auto;
}

table {
    width:50%;
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 0px; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

td {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0;
}
    
th {
    background: #395870;
    background: linear-gradient(#49708f, #293f50);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
        background: #f0f0f2;
}

p {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #ff3300;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
"@

$servers = Get-Content -Path Server_list.text|?{$_}|%{$_.trim()}

$session=@()

$servers|%{
    if(Test-Connection $_ -Quiet -Count 1)
    {
        $session+=New-PSSession $_
    }
}

$sblock={

$header=$using:style

$properties=@(
    @{Name="Process Name"; Expression = {$_.name}}, 
    @{Name="Memory (MB)"; Expression = {[Math]::Round(($_.WorkingSet / 1mb ),2)}}
)  

#Getting all process

$ComputerName = "<h1>Nom du serveur : $env:computername</h1>"
$ProcessInfo = Get-process  | Select-Object $properties | Sort-Object  -Property "Memory (MB)" -Descending |  ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header  -PreContent "<h2>Informations sur les processus</h2>"
$processReport = ConvertTo-HTML -Body " $ComputerName $ProcessInfo" -Title "Informations sur les processus Genetec" -PostContent "<p>Date de creation : $(Get-Date)<p>"

#Getting only Firefox process

$ProcessInfo_firefox = Get-process firefox | Select-Object $properties | Sort-Object  -Property "Memory (MB)" -Descending |  ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header  -PreContent "<h2>Informations sur les processus Firefox</h2>"
$firefoxReport = ConvertTo-HTML -Body " $ComputerName $ProcessInfo_firefox" -Title "Informations sur les processus Firefox" -PostContent "<p>Date de creation : $(Get-Date)<p>"

#Getting only Firefox process with more than 200Mb memory 

$ProcessInfo_firefox_plus200 =  Get-Process firefox | Select-Object @{Name="Process Name"; Expression = {$_.name}},@{Name="Memory (MB)"; Expression = {[Math]::Round(($_.WorkingSet / 1mb ),2)}} | where {$_.'Memory (MB)' -gt 300} | ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header  -PreContent "<h2>Informations sur les processus Firefox qui utilise plus que 200mb de RAM</h2>"
$firefoxPlus200Report = ConvertTo-HTML -Body " $ComputerName $ProcessInfo_firefox_plus200" -Title "Informations sur les processus Firefox qui utilise plus que 200mb de RAM" -PostContent "<p>Date de creation : $(Get-Date)<p>"

[PSCustomObject]@{
    processReport = $processReport
    firefoxReport = $firefoxReport
    firefoxPlus200Report = $firefoxPlus200Report
}

}

$results=invoke-command -Session $session -ScriptBlock $sblock

Remove-PSSession $session

#Here you have the report of your first server
$results[0].processReport
$results[0].firefoxReport
$results[0].firefoxPlus200Report

#The Results variable will contain the reports of all servers, you can use this variable to loop over each server
```

Comment: Hello Santiago,  First Thank you so much for the help I really appreciate it, Just I want to understand the part of the code which is responsible for building the results(HTML) in the local server ?

Comment: This code (your code) is building the HTML report in the remote servers. You usually want to grab all the results from the reports servers, and build the HTML locally. I personally don't use `ConvertTo-HTML`, I use here strings and insert the objects which usually are HTML tables where ever I need it.